# How to take Players to the Waiting Room in Realtime Multiplayer API

Tags: android, google-play-services, multiplayer, real-time-multiplayer

I'm unable to take the Players to waiting room...They are going to Waiting Room but i m facing problem that Room only get connected when all the required players gets connected.Such as I want 4 Player game In waiting room, I want to show Connected player name as soon as they connect to room but Room is  only Connected when all 4 player Shows up

```
 Bundle autoMatchCriteria = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(nop, nop, 0);

    // build the room config:
    RoomConfig roomConfig =
            RoomConfig.builder(mRoomUpdateCallback)
                    .setOnMessageReceivedListener(mOnRealTimeMessageReceivedListener)
                    .setRoomStatusUpdateCallback( mRoomStatusUpdateCallback)
                    .setAutoMatchCriteria(autoMatchCriteria)
                    .build();

    // create room:
    Games.getRealTimeMultiplayerClient(this,  GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
            .create(roomConfig);
```

Comment: Have you tried checking this part of the document: [Connecting Players](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer#connecting_players)? There are examples there that may help you.